# getting a local stored json file into html

Tags: javascript, html, json

does anyone know how I could get a local stored item (json) into html through javascript?
I'm currently getting an error after the new object is parsed and the data comes through null

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: what is `local stored item` ? localStorage? DOM data, a variable in javascript? a field value?

Comment: Yeah its a localStorage piece which was put together in Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, use the `.data()` method:

```
$( "body" ).data( "foo", 52 );
$( "body" ).data( "foo" ); // 52
```

Comment: date() ?? Never heard of that..

Comment: @guyfawkes should be `.data()`.  Edit is awaiting approval.

Comment: @freginold tnk.. I don't know why my horography corrector have changed it.